# How should I rewrite this long conditional statement to be an array with iterations

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to figure out the best way to rewrite this if statement as it is too long and has alot of OR clauses which are quite tedious. Surely this can be written in a cleaner fashion and I'm trying to figure out the best course of action to rewrite this code. I was thinking that maybe I should put all of the conditionals into an array and then write a for loop to iterate over each condition or is there a better way more concise way?

Thanks for your help

```js
if (
      VS_TDO1 == '11' ||
      VS_TDO2 == '11' ||
      VS_TDO3 == '11' ||
      VS_TDO4 == '11' ||
      VS_TDO5 == '11' ||
      VS_TDO6 == '11' ||
      VS_TDO7 == '11' ||
      VS_TDO8 == '11' ||
      VS_TDO9 == '11' ||
      VS_TD10 == '11' ||
      VS_TD11 == '11' ||
      VS_TD12 == '11'
    ) {
      VI_TDCF = VI_TDCF + 1;
    }
```

Comment: How you structure VS_TDO1, VS_TDO2,.... data ? Is they are in array or just variable holding value ?

Comment: A switch statement or Array structure would be a better for readability, but that depends on how your variables are initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array
>   passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a
>   Boolean value.

```
const arr = [VS_TDO1, VS_TDO2, VS_TDO3, ..]
if (arr.some((elem) => elem == "11")){
     VI_TDCF = VI_TDCF + 1;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo `Array.same()` -> `Array.some()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `includes`:

```
const arr = [VS_TDO1, TS_TDO2, VS_TDO3, ...];
if (arr.includes("11")) VI_TDCF++;
```

For older environments:

```
var arr = [VS_TDO1, TS_TDO2, VS_TDO3, ...];
if (arr.indexOf("11") != -1) VI_TDCF++;
```

Comment: `includes` not supported by IE lower versions. Use `indexOf` instead.

Comment: True @Soham - fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `VS_TODO1, VS_TODO2, ....` are in a array. Then you can easily check if a value includes in that array using javascript `includes` function.

```js
let VS_TODO1 = '11', VS_TODO2 = '12', VS_TODO3 = '13';
const arr = [VS_TODO1, VS_TODO2, VS_TODO3];

if(arr.includes('11')) {
  console.log('condition match');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support IE browser, go with `indexOf` instead `includes`

```js
const arr = ["11", "12"];

if(arr.indexOf('11') > -1) {
  console.log('condition match'); // condition match
}
```